# How can I configure Unity-Container to register a class by providing that class a string value?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, unity-container

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 based app. I am trying to use [Unity.Mvc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Mvc/) container to help me with dependency injection.

I have the following `DbContext` class

```
public class MainContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    // .....

    public MainContext(string connectionName)
        : base(connectionName)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<MainContext>(null);
    }
}
```

The production value I want to use when constructing the `MainContext` class is `DefaultConnection`. I want to register the `MainContext` class into the container and tell Unity to provide the `DefaultConnection` string to the constructor when using resolving it.

I tried the following

```
container.RegisterType<MainContext>("DefaultConnection", new PerRequestLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<string>("DefaultConnection")));
```

Also tried this

```
container.RegisterType<MainContext>("DefaultConnection", new PerRequestLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor("DefaultConnection"));
```

But I keep getting the following error

```
Resolution of the dependency failed, type = 'System.Web.Mvc.IController', name = 'MyProject.Controllers.HomeController'.
Exception occurred while: while resolving.
Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The type String cannot be constructed. You must configure the container to supply this value.
-----------------------------------------------
At the time of the exception, the container was: 
Resolving MyProject.Controllers.HomeController, MyProject.Controllers.HomeController (mapped from System.Web.Mvc.IController, MyProject.Controllers.HomeController)
Resolving parameter 'unitOfWork' of constructor MyProject.Controllers.HomeController(MyProject.Repositories.Contracts.IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
Resolving MyProject.Repositories.UnitOfWork,(none) (mapped from MyProject.Repositories.Contracts.UnitsOfWork.IUnitOfWork, (none))
Resolving parameter 'context' of constructor MyProject.Repositories.UnitOfWork(MyProject.Contexts.MainContext context)
Resolving MyProject.Contexts.MainContext,(none)
Resolving parameter 'connectionName' of constructor MyProject.Contexts.MainContext(System.String connectionName)
Resolving System.String,(none)
```

A workaround would be to change my `MainContext` class to this

```
public class MainContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    // .....

    public MainContext(string connectionName)
        : base(connectionName)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<MainContext>(null);
    }

    public MainContext(string connectionName)
        : this("DefaultConnection")
    {

    }
}
```

Then register my class like so

```
container.RegisterType<MainContext>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor());
```

But, I don't want to couple my implementation with a specific connection-name. I want the IoC to provide the connection name to `MainContext`. In another words, I want to be able to swap out connection name without changing the `MainContext` class.

How can I correctly tell Unity-Container to register the `MainContext` class and use a the `DefaultConnection` when it is constructed?

Answer (score 1):

This does not directly answer my question but gave me a flexible workaround.

I created the following interface

```
public interface IDatabaseConnection
{
    string NameOrConnectionString { get; }
}
```

Then I created the following implementations of this class

```
public class DefaultDatabaseConnection: IDatabaseConnection
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public DefaultDatabaseConnection()
    {
         NameOrConnectionString = "DefaultConnection";
    }

    public DefaultDatabaseConnection(string connectionName)
    {
        NameOrConnectionString = connectionName;
    }
}
```

Then I changed my `MainContext` class to this

```
public class MainContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    // .....

    public MainContext(IDatabaseConnection connection)
        : base(connection.NameOrConnectionString)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<MainContext>(null);
    }
}
```

Finally, I registered my classes like so

```
container.RegisterType<IDatabaseConnection, DefaultDatabaseConnection>("DefaultDatabaseConnection", new InjectionConstructor());
container.RegisterType<MainCompanyContext>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<IDatabaseConnection>("DefaultDatabaseConnection")));
```

I will accept other answers over mine if a better answer is presented, so please guide me if there is simpler way or if there is a way to provide a raw string to the `InjectionConstructor` class.

Answer (score 0):

**Static Value**

If you want to hardcode a string to be passed to the constructor, you can simply do:

```
container.RegisterType<IMyInterface, MyClass>(
    new InjectionConstructor(
        "ThisIsAHardCopedString",
        new ResolvedParameter<IOtherInput>()));
```

**Parameterized Value**

However, if you want to use a `string` from the configuration file, for example, you can do this:

```
container.RegisterType<IMyInterface, MyClass>(
    new InjectionConstructor(
        new ResolvedParameter<string>("TheNameOfMyString"),
        new ResolvedParameter<IOtherInput>()));
```

And in your main project, you register the string:

```
container.RegisterInstance<string>("TheNameOfMyString", Settings.Default.ParameterName);
```

It looks like you want solution 1, but I'd suggest solution 2, to make it easier to change in the future.

Note: You can have `LifetimeManagers` coexisting with the solution, it's just not relevant for the solution.